# How to create a button drawable in android?

Tags: android, button, drawable

i want to create a button like this .I created a drawable like this 
[image: figure 1]

I created a drawable like this.`

```
<!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <padding
            android:bottom="3dp"
            android:right="3dp" />

        <solid android:color="#C0C0C0" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- Background -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/brick" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

But I got a button like this
[image: figure 2].
What else i have to do ?

Comment: you can add a top and left padding to the background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create something like this:

```
<item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:right="4dp" android:bottom="4dp">

                <!-- SHADOW LAYER -->
            </item>
            <item android:left="4dp" android:top="4dp">
                <!-- CONTENT LAYER-->
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the padding tag down in the Background like below:

```
<!-- Drop Shadow Stack -->
<item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#C0C0C0" />
</shape>
</item> 
<!-- Background -->
<item>
 <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
 <padding
        android:bottom="3dp"
        android:right="3dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/brick" />
</shape>
</item>
```